# NativeApplication DEACTIVATE-ACTIVATE app when in the background

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I have made a Flash Air game. While playing it, if I press the Home button on my Android device, I get to the phone's menu yet I still get to listen to the game's music, which means that the game still keeps on fully working.

I would like my app to pause when not in the foreground.

I've seen these codes but apparently I'm doing something wrong cause they aren't working probably...

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, handleApplicationDeactivated);
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, handleApplicationActivated);
```

I've listed the:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
```

Could you help me with the proper code?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will run the onPause when you press the home button, and onResume when you get back in your app.
SoundMixer.stopAll(); will stop ALL sounds that are playing.

```
    this.stage.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.DEACTIVATE, onPause, false, 0, true);

    this.stage.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.ACTIVATE, onResume, false, 0, true);



    private function onPause(event:flash.events.Event):void
    {

        //here save your games state.

        //then stop ALL sound from playing with the following line:
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        //Remember to import flash.media.SoundMixer;

    }
    private function onResume(event:flash.events.Event):void
    {
         //here you start the sounds again, for example: 
        sound.play();

    }
```