# How to reset Accelerometer Event As3

Tags: actionscript-3

In my project, at the start of game accelerometer event works fine. While game reaches the game over page and click on restart button. All the objects are working good when restarting the whole game also all values have been reset but accelerometer is not working.

Thanks in Advance.

The code follows:

```
if (Accelerometer.isSupported)
{ 
    acc = new Accelerometer();
    acc.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE,updateFn);
}
public function updateFn(e:AccelerometerEvent):void 
{ 
    targetX = e.accelerationX * 9.8; 
}
```

Comment: This needs code, especially the setting and handling accelerometer events. You are probably not setting a listener on the event and invalidate the previous one somehow. Also, please do not post new questions for the very same problem and with the same content, but edit your old question instead, this will result in it being treated as new.

Comment: I have entered the code below for accelerometer event.kindly check with it.

Comment: You should have edited the question (there's an "edit" link below the question text and tags, use that one). I moved the code into the question for you.

Comment: This code is apparently located on some frame. Please check what is `acc` and is it defined before and after you perform a game restart routine. It's possible that you need to move accelerometer initialization code somewhere away from game restart code, so the `acc=new Accelerometer()` is not called when you restart the game, so you can use one and single instance of `acc` during multiple game sessions.

Comment: acc is defined in the document class at the start of game. My accelerometer event is in custom class not in the restart code.The problem I am facing while restarting the game accelerometer update function is not working.

Comment: Are you turning off or removing the acc var on game over.  Also, does this code run again on restart, so you're reassigning the acc var?  Mayb check to see if acc already exists

Answer (score 0):

Just register the Accelerator once the app was launched/activated and save it's value to global variables on each accelerator update and disabled it each time the app is put to the background / deactivated / exit. Eg:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, handleApplicationDeactivated);
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, handleApplicationActivated);

function handleApplicationActivated( e:Event):void {

   // Check if Accelerometer is already activated 
   if( acc != null ) return; 

   acc = new Accelerometer();
   acc.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE,update);
}
function update( e:AccelerometerEvent ):void {
  GlobalVars.accX = e.accelerationX;
  GlobalVars.accY = e.accelerationY;
  GlobalVars.accZ = e.accelerationZ;
}
function handleApplicationDeactivated( e:Event):void {
   acc.removeEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE,update);
   acc = null;
}
```

edit: you might will want to use this activate/deactivate code instead : [NativeApplication DEACTIVATE-ACTIVATE app when in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855239/nativeapplication-deactivate-activate-app-when-in-the-background) since the NativeApplication have some issues.